# Is it possible to make counter in datetime module?

Tags: python, datetime

I'm trying to make program that will automatically fill out information in excel about work hours for company I work with. Most of is just PyAutoGUI and automatically filling out constant numbers and saving files.

The problem is I have to change dates in each week from Monday to Friday (so without weekends). Is there any way I can make a datetime counter that will go from for example from 03/30/2020 (Monday) to today's date?

Comment: Are you counting down to the next date?

Comment: Yes im counting next date it should write 03/31/2020, 04/01/2020... and so on... each date is for each excel file... i have to make 200+ files

Comment: Phooey, I'm not super experienced with that, but this looks like a nice example: [link](https://gist.github.com/Gadgetoid/b771131b1adb624b4753)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following:

```py
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta

def day_counter(start_day):
    day = datetime.strptime(start_day, '%m/%d/%Y').date()
    tomorrow = date.today() + timedelta(days=1)
    while day != tomorrow:
        if day.weekday() not in {5, 6}:
            yield day.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
        day += timedelta(days=1)
```

This then

```py
for day in day_counter('03/30/2020'):
    print(day)
```

produces the days starting from 03/30/2020 until today without the weekends:

```
03/30/2020
03/31/2020
04/01/2020
04/02/2020
04/03/2020
04/06/2020
04/07/2020
... 
11/26/2020
11/27/2020
11/30/2020
12/01/2020
12/02/2020
12/03/2020
12/04/2020
```

Comment: Thanks for the source code you saved me hours of work!!!!